# Using only CSS is it possible to set a property based on class name?

Tags: css

Say I have some css like:

```
.modal-350 {
    width: 350px;
}
.modal-400 {
    width: 400px;
}
.modal-500 {
    width: 500px;
}
```

etc. Using only CSS is it possible to set the width (or other property) just from the class name?

I know in javascript this is easy and also I could just use:

```
.modal-auto {
    display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
```

It's not production code, I'm just curious.

Comment: No, that's not how CSS works. The closest you can get is to [use `attr()` to reference other HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), and that's not well-supported.

Comment: I didn't think so, but still it was worth knowing for sure!

Comment: That may work for a single element or a section, But when you have to create a whole website that will make everything complicated. So be wise while you select class names.

Comment: It was just example code for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even though we [can use variables in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), we can only do so in property values and not in selector names. So something like this will **not** work:

```
.modal-$size {
    width: ${size}px;
}
```

You can, however, use a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), and generate such rules automagically, given the requested sizes.

A SASS example:

```
$modal-sizes: 50 100 200 500;

%modal-default {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: red;
  background: green;
  border-color: blue;
}

@mixin modals {
  @each $size in $modal-sizes {
      .modal-#{$size} {
        @extend %modal-default;
        width: #{$size}px;
      }
  }
}

@include modals;
```

This will compile as:

```
.modal-50, .modal-100, .modal-200, .modal-500 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: red;
  background: green;
  border-color: blue;
}

.modal-50 {
  width: 50px;
}

.modal-100 {
  width: 100px;
}

.modal-200 {
  width: 200px;
}

.modal-500 {
  width: 500px;
}
```